# An error while using num_rows method in php

Tags: php, mysqli, authentication, fatal-error

I designed a login form, but while processing it has a fatal error which I have no idea how to fix that.
here are my codes:

dbConnection.php:

```
<?php 
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$dbname = 'fashionshop';

$conn = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$dbname);

if($conn->connect_error){
    die('Connection Failed:' .$conn->connect_error);
}
//echo "Connected Successfully";
?>
```

userloginprocess.php:

```
<?php require_once 'dbConnection.php'; ?>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['client-login-submit'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users
        WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password1 = '".$password."' LIMIT 1";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if($conn->num_rows($result) == 1){  // this is line 14
        header('location:welcome.php');
    }else{
        header('location:error.php');
    }
}else{
    header('location:notworking.php');
}

?>
```

html form:

```
<form action="inc/userloginprocess.php" method="post">
    <h1>LOG IN</h1>
    <input placeholder="Username" type="text" name="username" id="username">
    <input placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password" id="password">
    <input type="submit" name="client-login-submit" value="LOG IN">
    <p>Forget Your Password? <a href="#">RESET</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">SIGN UP</a></p>
</form>
```

and finally the error when I submit the form:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::num_rows() in C:\xampp\htdocs\fashionshop\inc\userloginprocess.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\fashionshop\inc\userloginprocess.php on line 14
```

I would be grateful if you help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong object in getting the number of rows. Use `$result` instead of `$conn`.

**Make**

`$conn->num_rows($result)`

**To:**

`$result->num_rows`

Comment: @faro621 if it is the correct answer, please accept the anwser. It lets others know that the question has been anwsered and gives the answerer the reputation he deserves